# Change Layout for UISegmentedControl?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uisegmentedcontrol

currently I'm using the SVSegmentedControl by Sam Vermette - works great, but I'm asking myself if it's possible to change the layout of the SVSegmentedControl or the UISegmentedControl in general?

I want to have 2 rows with 2 "cells" / row, is that somehow possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have 2 rows, each with two cells, this isn't a thing that you can change with default segmented control behavior.

If you want something that looks like a box with 4 sections and behaves like a segmented control (only allows one part to be selected) then create 2 segmented controls. Customize how "it"(they) look(s) with `backgroundImageForState:barMetrics:` and other similar methods. When you detect that one of the control's parts has been selected, then deselect all of the other parts in both controls.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the source code, it doesn't actually inherit from UISegmentedControl, instead from UIControl. So if you wan't to customise UISegmentedControl, your best bet looks like building a similarly behaving control from scratch.